# Loopback v3 relation users model and other model structure

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, relation

I Have Events model and this model there is Speakers and Attendees, Attendees and Speakers are users in the application.

how i can do it with relation in LoopBack? like: get event with his speakers and attendees

and how i can assign Attendee to event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Event could have one/Many speakers and many attendees, so the event relation should be like below

*event.json*

```
  "relations": {
    "speakers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Speaker",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "attendees": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Attendee",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

The speaker belongsTo to an event :

*speaker.json*

```
"relations": {
    "event": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Event",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

and finally an attendee belongs to an event

*attendee.json*

```
"relations": {
    "event": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Event",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

Putting the relations above will give you new endpoints in your explorer, now you can assign an attendee to an event using the POST method like below.

PS: Do not create the Attendee ID since the idInjection is TRUE so it will be created automatically just assign the eventId

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "id": "string",
  "eventId": "string"
}
```

> Note that you don't have to create a foreign key since loopback will
>   target the default id of each related model only if you need to use
>   custom ones.

---

**UPDATE**

To make it work on the built in **USER** Model, we should extend it first.

To extend the user model we should create a new one :

1. `slc loopback:model`
2. name it user (lowercase) because loopback is using User, or just pick any other name as customUser or whatever.
3. Select your datasource
4. Select **User** the model's base class this one will override the the built in User model
5. Expose via the REST API : (yes or no) as you wish

Once the model is created, edit the  **config-model.json** and disable the built in User model.

Add this property to User : `"public": false` (this will disable User from being shwon in the explorer)

```
"User": {
"dataSource": "MongoDs",
"public": false
}
```

Add Relation in **event.json** with the new user model

```
"relations": {
    "users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

Add Relation **user.json** with Event model

```
  "relations": {
    "event": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Event",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
```

Now you can assign a user to an event. However to assign a speaker or an attendee you should create type field like `"type" : { "type": "string"}` which could be `"attendee"` / `"speaker"`

To find users from your event model use this filter : `{include: 'users'}` in your `find()` function.

Comment: Thanks, but the Attendee and Speaker are users in the application, so if i create new user how to assign it to event?

Comment: @AlaaAlshaikh  Actually, it is not possible since it is a built in model and doesn't exist in your model folder so you have to create a new model and extend the user model then create the user via this new model. you can read about it here https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html I can try to make an example with this on your demand

Comment: Yes you are right i created extend model from user, but still i didn't get it.
yes if you can make an example will be helpful thanks alot

Comment: Thanks @Anouar Kacem, where should i add: 
"type" : { "type": "string"} 
and which api should i use to assign the attendee / speaker to event?

Comment: @AlaaAlshaikh you should use the user API and create it with eventId also you can create Remote Methods (Custom APIs) to get speakers and attendees for a specific event or just use the exisiting APIs and use filters in your query get by user type